# Linq and Entity Migrations with specific schemas in PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, postgresql

With **PostgreSQL** I can perform queries against tables in a specific schema, or across multiple schemas at once. I'm wondering how to handle two scenarios:

1. How do you specify either multiple schemas or a single schema when performing a query using Linq to EF?

   - I'm thinking I might be able to perform some connection string voodoo, but it seems like that could get very ugly very quick.
2. How do you perform Entity Migrations for multiple schemas?

   - You can specify a schema as a `DataAnnotation` on the object (via `[Table]`), but you can't specify multiple schemas at once (from what I can tell).

Any help at all is much appreciated.

Comment: Are the table names the same? ex SchemaA.Address and SchemaB.Address? Otherwise I don't know why you need to specify the schema in your linq query.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin same table names.

Answer (score 1):

For #1, There is no way, to work with schemas directly in a Linq-To-Entities query. I believe they are adding some functionality here in EF6, but I'm guessing you don't want to wait until then.

There is one work around, which I have used in SQL Server 2008, using `Synonyms` (I believe PostgreSQL also has `Synonym` functionality).

For example, if your table names are `dbo.Address` and `read.Address`, you would create a `Synonym` for `read.Address`, named `read.Address_read`, then you would add the `Synonym` to your EF datamodel, instead of the table itself. This gives you the ability to perform any and all queries against multiple schemas at once, because EF thinks these tables have different names.